# Azure VM extensions no longer available?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, iaas

In one of my older VM's in Azure I see in these VM extension:

[image]

But in new VM's I can't add these when I choose add extensions. Are these no longer available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, they are available, i'm pretty sure they are even called the same:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/oms-windows
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/oms-linux

Comment: I can't seem to add them through the Azure Portal

Comment: yeah, i think i dont see it either, you can use arm templates\powershell\cli to install it